# Get the mean and standard deviation based on groupings from another dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

The rownames of `clin.info` corresponds with the column names of `mrna`. For each of the `subtype` column value in `clin.info`, I want to obtain the `rowMeans` and standard deviation from the `mrna` dataframe.
This means that for all the subtype groups (`1a`, `1b`, `1c` etc), calculate the average and SD of the corresponding values in the `mrna` dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)
# compute the mean and standard deviation.
clin.info %>%
  group_by(subtype) %>%
  filter(rownames(clin.info) %in% colnames(mrna)) %>%
  summarise(
    count_subtype = n(),
    mean_time = rowMeans(mrna, na.rm=TRUE),
    sd_time = sd(mrna, na.rm = TRUE)
  )
```

Traceback:

```
Error in `filter()`:
ℹ In argument: `rownames(clin.info) %in% colnames(mrna)`.
ℹ In group 1: `subtype = 1a`.
Caused by error:
! `..1` must be of size 44 or 1, not size 202.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Data:

```
> dput(clin.info)
structure(list(subtype = c("2a", "1a", "1b", "1a", "1a", "1b", 
"2b", "2b", "2a", "1a", "2b", "1b", "1c", "2b", "2a", "2b", "1b", 
"2b", "2b", "1c", "1c", "2b", "1c", "2c", "1a", "1a", "2b", "1c", 
"1a", "1c", "2b", "2a", "2c", "2a", "1a", "1a", "1b", "1a", "1b", 
"1a", "2a", "1a", "1c", "1a", "1c", "2b", "1a", "2a", "1c", "2a", 
"1a", "2b", "2b", "2c", "2b", "2c", "2b", "2a", "2b", "2a", "2b", 
"2a", "2a", "2a", "2b", "2b", "2b", "2c", "2c", "2b", "2b", "2b", 
"2a", "2b", "1c", "2b", "2a", "2b", "2b", "2a", "2b", "2b", "1a", 
"1b", "1c", "1a", "1a", "2a", "1c", "1a", "1a", "1c", "2a", "2b", 
"2a", "1c", "2a", "1a", "1a", "1c", "1a", "2c", "1a", "1b", "2c", 
"2a", "2c", "2b", "1a", "2c", "1a", "1a", "1c", "2b", "1a", "1c", 
"1b", "1c", "2c", "1c", "2b", "1a", "2c", "1c", "2a", "1c", "1c", 
"2a", "2b", "2a", "1c", "2c", "2a", "1c", "1b", "1c", "2a", "1a", 
"1a", "2b", "2c", "2a", "1a", "2b", "1c", "2a", "1a", "2c", "2c", 
"2a", "1b", "1b", "1b", "2b", "1a", "2b", "2b", "1a", "2c", "2c", 
"2b", "2a", "1c", "2b", "2a", "1b", "2b", "1b", "1a", "2b", "1a", 
"2b", "1a", "1c", "1a", "1b", "1c", "1c", "1a", "1b", "2a", "2a", 
"2b", "1c", "1c", "1c", "1c", "1c", "1c", "1c", "1b", "2b", "2a", 
"2a", "1c", "1a", "1a", "1a", "1a", "2b", "1c", "2a")), row.names = c("TCGA.Y8.A8S1.01A", 
"TCGA.Y8.A8S0.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A8RZ.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A8RY.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A897.01A", 
"TCGA.Y8.A896.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A895.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A894.01A", "TCGA.WN.A9G9.01A", 
"TCGA.V9.A7HT.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9Q1.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9Q0.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PZ.01A", 
"TCGA.UZ.A9PX.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PV.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PU.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PS.01A", 
"TCGA.UZ.A9PR.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PP.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PO.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PN.01A", 
"TCGA.UZ.A9PM.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PL.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PK.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PJ.01A", 
"TCGA.UN.AAZ9.01A", "TCGA.SX.A7SS.01A", "TCGA.SX.A7SR.01A", "TCGA.SX.A7SQ.01A", 
"TCGA.SX.A7SP.01A", "TCGA.SX.A7SO.01A", "TCGA.SX.A7SN.01A", "TCGA.SX.A7SM.01A", 
"TCGA.SX.A71U.01A", "TCGA.SX.A71R.01A", "TCGA.Q2.A5QZ.01A", "TCGA.PJ.A5Z9.01A", 
"TCGA.PJ.A5Z8.01A", "TCGA.P4.AAVM.01A", "TCGA.P4.AAVL.01A", "TCGA.P4.A5ED.01A", 
"TCGA.P4.A5EB.01A", "TCGA.P4.A5EA.01A", "TCGA.P4.A5E8.01A", "TCGA.P4.A5E7.01A", 
"TCGA.P4.A5E6.01A", "TCGA.MH.A855.01A", "TCGA.MH.A562.01A", "TCGA.MH.A560.01A", 
"TCGA.MH.A55Z.01A", "TCGA.KV.A74V.01A", "TCGA.KV.A6GE.01A", "TCGA.KV.A6GD.01A", 
"TCGA.J7.A8I2.01A", "TCGA.J7.8537.01A", "TCGA.J7.6720.01A", "TCGA.IZ.A6M8.01A", 
"TCGA.IZ.8196.01A", "TCGA.IZ.8195.01A", "TCGA.IA.A83W.01A", "TCGA.IA.A83V.01A", 
"TCGA.IA.A40Y.01A", "TCGA.IA.A40X.01A", "TCGA.IA.A40U.01A", "TCGA.HE.A5NL.01A", 
"TCGA.HE.A5NK.01A", "TCGA.HE.A5NJ.01A", "TCGA.HE.A5NI.01A", "TCGA.HE.A5NH.01A", 
"TCGA.HE.A5NF.01A", "TCGA.HE.7130.01A", "TCGA.HE.7129.01A", "TCGA.HE.7128.01A", 
"TCGA.GL.A9DE.01A", "TCGA.GL.A9DD.01A", "TCGA.GL.A9DC.01A", "TCGA.GL.A59R.01A", 
"TCGA.GL.A4EM.01A", "TCGA.GL.8500.01A", "TCGA.GL.7966.01A", "TCGA.GL.7773.01A", 
"TCGA.GL.6846.01A", "TCGA.G7.A8LE.01A", "TCGA.G7.A8LD.01A", "TCGA.G7.A8LC.01A", 
"TCGA.G7.A8LB.01A", "TCGA.G7.A4TM.01A", "TCGA.G7.7502.01A", "TCGA.G7.7501.01A", 
"TCGA.G7.6797.01A", "TCGA.G7.6796.01A", "TCGA.G7.6795.01A", "TCGA.G7.6793.01A", 
"TCGA.G7.6792.01A", "TCGA.G7.6790.01A", "TCGA.G7.6789.01A", "TCGA.F9.A97G.01A", 
"TCGA.F9.A8NY.01A", "TCGA.F9.A7VF.01A", "TCGA.F9.A7Q0.01A", "TCGA.F9.A4JJ.01A", 
"TCGA.EV.5903.01A", "TCGA.EV.5902.01A", "TCGA.EV.5901.01A", "TCGA.DZ.6135.01A", 
"TCGA.DZ.6134.01A", "TCGA.DZ.6133.01A", "TCGA.DZ.6132.01A", "TCGA.DZ.6131.01A", 
"TCGA.DW.7963.01B", "TCGA.DW.7842.01A", "TCGA.DW.7841.01A", "TCGA.DW.7840.01A", 
"TCGA.DW.7839.01A", "TCGA.DW.7838.01A", "TCGA.DW.7837.01A", "TCGA.DW.7834.01A", 
"TCGA.DW.5561.01A", "TCGA.DW.5560.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7062.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7061.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.7060.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7059.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7058.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7056.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.7055.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7053.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7051.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7050.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.7049.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7048.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7046.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7044.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.5894.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5893.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5892.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5891.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.5890.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5889.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5888.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5887.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.5885.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5883.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5882.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5881.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.5880.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5879.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5878.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5877.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.5875.01A", "TCGA.B9.A8YI.01A", "TCGA.B9.A8YH.01A", "TCGA.B9.A69E.01A", 
"TCGA.B9.A5W9.01A", "TCGA.B9.A5W8.01A", "TCGA.B9.A5W7.01A", "TCGA.B9.A44B.01A", 
"TCGA.B9.7268.01A", "TCGA.B9.5156.01A", "TCGA.B9.5155.01A", "TCGA.B3.A6W5.01A", 
"TCGA.B3.8121.01A", "TCGA.B1.A657.01A", "TCGA.B1.A654.01A", "TCGA.B1.A47O.01A", 
"TCGA.B1.A47N.01A", "TCGA.B1.A47M.01A", "TCGA.B1.7332.01A", "TCGA.B1.5398.01A", 
"TCGA.AL.A5DJ.01A", "TCGA.AL.7173.01A", "TCGA.A4.A57E.01A", "TCGA.A4.8630.01A", 
"TCGA.A4.8517.01A", "TCGA.A4.8311.01A", "TCGA.A4.8098.01A", "TCGA.A4.7997.01A", 
"TCGA.A4.7996.01A", "TCGA.A4.7915.01A", "TCGA.A4.7734.01A", "TCGA.A4.7585.01A", 
"TCGA.A4.7584.01A", "TCGA.A4.7583.01A", "TCGA.A4.7288.01A", "TCGA.5P.A9KE.01A", 
"TCGA.5P.A9JY.01A", "TCGA.5P.A9JU.01A", "TCGA.4A.A93Y.01A", "TCGA.4A.A93X.01A", 
"TCGA.4A.A93W.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JQ.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JO.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A", 
"TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A"), class = "data.frame")

> dput(mrna[1:10,1:10])
structure(c(6.32723473285944, 6.12006753804177, 7.084708339451, 
6.68389982749589, 6.64959906913921, 6.57218416829139, 5.93820103843076, 
6.61429795497195, 6.68435329542923, 6.77328200174798, 5.90606341714547, 
6.23889181401892, 6.92831212860709, 6.80056846842946, 6.68681275634207, 
6.65948789110786, 6.11947088984163, 6.70428834563649, 6.70083198265254, 
6.79365356327255, 5.83975605285168, 6.35191888050695, 6.70284509253169, 
6.67882080723944, 6.66725810982162, 6.65285308886298, 6.12663105421854, 
6.71109019864985, 6.67544754463686, 6.80600476574279, 6.40229168313991, 
6.23351731501, 7.05190682367583, 6.70975527293371, 6.7151354219556, 
6.67360376595377, 6.07903505135323, 6.67869544585629, 6.80381309964596, 
6.85315495617517, 5.9180717925086, 6.24119052638047, 6.89395173838737, 
6.7631608911137, 6.70646751367687, 6.65716302681663, 5.99400340296877, 
6.67560052362712, 6.7376385920734, 6.80916225207066, 6.25364999373256, 
6.30113549355317, 6.7890342215761, 6.74760751770836, 6.73105813002929, 
6.61137563487618, 6.21638860397226, 6.67889751740184, 6.58834760414241, 
6.84558281744234, 5.57013797762632, 6.39035908015929, 6.88679393427576, 
6.6543208719331, 6.6599019712593, 6.65359376075996, 6.38120195213167, 
6.71197634141007, 6.86002727965528, 6.85839176503481, 5.46867846459722, 
6.52425052517135, 6.8048725410581, 6.78810410961374, 6.6341431912473, 
6.69586650630468, 6.09282698473652, 6.7114039325652, 6.80024590501626, 
6.82810054970223, 6.41572939129525, 6.01835421047842, 6.9507792354424, 
6.65047189766905, 6.64139794312131, 6.61944137947836, 6.23681055924707, 
6.61791043730588, 6.73525577793128, 6.8370861309086, 6.12089654252168, 
6.1427679721791, 6.96220959504292, 6.85858777134064, 6.6012546031416, 
6.70055740296319, 6.0216044286447, 6.66561468579511, 6.68419347275145, 
6.82305300353865), dim = c(10L, 10L), dimnames = list(c("A1BG", 
"A2LD1", "A2M", "A4GALT", "AAAS", "AACS", "AADAT", "AAGAB", "AAK1", 
"AAMP"), c("TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A")))
```

Comment: Try `rownames(cur_group())` instead of `rownames(clin.info)`

Comment: @RicardoSemiãoeCastro it returns `Can't recycle `count_subtype` (size 13457) to size 0.`

Comment: @melolili you deleted then reposted this question after it got a negative vote - thats generally frowned upon and exacerbates the negative impact on your account (if you delete a question, it [counts double against your question record](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290545/how-is-a-positive-question-record-calculated)). In the future, you should edit it to update the question.

Comment: I'm confused -- "For each of the subtype column value in clin.info, I want to obtain the rowMeans and standard deviation from the mrna dataframe." But `mrna` doesn't have subtypes, it has column names which look like they will coincide with rownames in `clin.info` (but not in the example ranges). For instance, clin.info has rownames like "TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A" and mrna has column names like "TCGA.Y8.A8S1.01A", which seems like they're supposed to be linked (when they match).

Comment: For example, the `subtype` column for `TCGA.Y8.A8S1.01A` and `XYZ` rowname is `1a`, whereas `ABC` and `DEF` correspond with `1b`. I want to get the mean and standard deviation of these groups based on corresponding values in the `mrna` dataframe.

Comment: To make this clearer for us, would it be okay to rename the `mrna` columns in your sample to match rownames in `clin.info`, so that you can show what an expected result would be? You mention that "The rownames of clin.info corresponds with the column names of mrna" in your data, but that's not the case for your excerpt.